# How do I get a list of people that shared my facebook post?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

How do I get a list of people that shared my post?  I can see publicly shared instances in the facebook, but I want to get it using graph-api?

Comment: That is not possible.

Comment: may i ask what for?

Comment: @luschn it's for picking random people for prize from people who shared the post.

Comment: you are not allowed to reward users for sharing something on their personal wall.

Answer (score 0):

The [/{post-id}/sharedposts](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/post/sharedposts/) edge does exist; but you won’t be able to get any shares made by users, unless those were users of your app as well, *and* granted it `user_posts` permission to read their posts.

So unless in very specific scenarios, like f.e. where you had a website community of people that are using your app and granted it the permission, and they share each other’s stuff, you likely won’t be able to get much here.

Shares made by pages are probably different, you might be able to get those post IDs. But then you won’t be able to get any further info about those posts, unless your app has the Page Public Content Access feature approved (and the allowed use cases for that are very limited, so Facebook will likely not grant it in review for such a purpose.)